# How to show the number of characters in textarea only with template variable?

Tags: angular

I want to show the number of characters in `textarea` only with a template variable (reference) `editor`.

**My Pseudo Code:**

```html
<p>{{editor.textarea.length}</p>
<div>
    <textarea name="" id="" cols="30" rows="10" #editor></textarea>
</div>
```

I know we can solve it with the following way but it is not what I am looking for.

```js
export class AppComponent {
  desc:string = "";
}
```

and

```html
<textarea [(ngModel)]="desc"></textarea>
<div>{{desc.length}}</div>
```

### Question:

How to show the number of characters in `textarea`  only with template variable (without `@ViewChild` as well)?

Comment: You mean this should be done without taking any help from .ts file (like creating method to return value)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

replace `textarea` with `value` and add  `(keyup)="null"` in html tag

```
<p>{{editor.value.length}}</p>
<div>
    <textarea name="" id="" cols="30" rows="10" (keyup)="null" #editor></textarea>
</div>
```

Stackblitz : [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-yf4lrv?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: i tried it work fine change <p>{{editor.value.length}</p> to  <p>{{editor.value.length}}</p>
i think angular added it in change detection after apply event bind on html

Comment: add ngModel:`<textarea name="" id="" cols="30" rows="10" ngModel #editor></textarea>`

Comment: Please provide Stackblitz example if possible

Comment: check [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-yf4lrv?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: @ProSheta Thanks for your example. Please explain me how it is working like that.

Comment: @Exception, the problem (happens on Angular 14, not in Angular 13 or bellow) is that angular need know that "some has changed" to "repaint". ProSheta use `(keyup)="null"` -I suggested use ngModel-. A simple input (or textarea) not indicate to Angular that need repaint. the `#editor` is a [template reference variable](https://angular.io/guide/template-reference-variables) and in .html you can access to the html element indicate by the variable. The htmlElement "editor" has a property "value" that is a string. the length property of a string is the length of the string

Answer (score 0):

Another approach:

```html
<p #out></p>
<div>
    <textarea (input)="out.innerHTML=editor.value.length.toString()" #editor></textarea>
</div>
```